# Flutter jsonDecode return type is `dynamic` whereas Album factory method expects a `Map<String, dynamic>`

Tags: flutter

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'http.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({this.userId, this.id, this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AlbumFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AlbumToJson(this);
}

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  var resp = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1');
  var A = Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body)); // Error line

  print(A.title);
  print(A.toJson());
}
```

Error - At `var A = Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body));` is `The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.dartargument_type_not_assignable`.

`jsonDecode` return type is `dynamic` whereas Album factory method expects a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

It shows compile-time error but I am able to get desired outputs in debug console.

How should we solve this?

Comment: you can try catch code var A = Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body) as Map<String, dynamic>); to see if json is illegal or something, if json is legal this should be problem

Answer (score 2):

Adding @Ulas's comment as an answer here -

We can use `as` keyword with jsonDecode for it to return a specific type rather that `dynamic` -

`var A = Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);`

Comment: I tried this and am getting the following error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String,dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: @YousufFarhan It means that in your case, the return value of `jsonDecode` is of type `List<dynamic>`. So you have to write it this way: `jsonDecode(resp.body) as List<dynamic>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that problem since `jsonDecode` returns a `dynamic` type. You'd have to convert that `dynamic` type to a `Map<String,dynamic>`.

Instead of:

```
Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body));
```

Do this:

```
Album.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(resp.body)));
```

Comment: This is incorrect answer since jsonDecode is returning dynamic which we need to change. `var A = Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body) as Map<String, dynamic>); ` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var A = Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body as Map<String, dynamic>)); // no error
```

Add some try-catch blocks. Allot of stuff could go wrong when you send a request :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though, this is just pseudocode. This is incorrect answer since jsonDecode is returning dynamic which we need to change. `var A = Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(resp.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);` works fine.